# How do I deal with a protoss army containing high templars as a zerg?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-zerg, starcraft-protoss

Well, I play team games mostly but besides team battles, I have been in a few battles which was just the protoss and me, the zerg. And, I struggled a lot. Whatever composition I have in the army (except for brood lords, haven't been in a 1v1 battle with brood lords on my side yet), the high templars literally screwed my whole army when we clashed. All I could do was try-to-hit and run.

How am I supposed to counter this army of his - Stalker / Zealot / Archon / High Templar ? How should I deal with his army as zerg?

Comment: not let them get templars, or be amazing with Micro/APM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to deal with High Templars as Zerg is to have a Roach heavy army.
Roaches can take up to 2½ storm, and the burrow ability is great.

The Protoss will naturally add Immortals to counter the Roaches.
This is why you would add speedlings to your army as well.

The speedlings serves two purposes.

1. To deal with Immortals
2. To deny expansions

Then I would recommend going for Broodlords or Swarm Hosts.

So all-over I would recommend:

- Roach heavy army
- Speedlings
- Swarm Hosts
- Hydras (if the toss adds air)

Comment: This is really stupid advice. If the toss is going HT/Immo they have a ton of minerals so they are going to dump that into zelots. You zerglings are never ever going to touch the immortals. Anyways lings die in less than 1/2 a sec to storm you can fight with them only harras. Also immortal stalker walks all over roaches add in the dps of storm and your army melts. Roach ling is the worse thing you could do vs templar immortal.

Comment: @ClassicThunder When the Protoss have HTs with Storm, we must assume that its at least mid-game. The Zerg should have started to tech for higher tier units like Swarmhosts and Hydras getting set for either Ultras or Broods. Immortal Stalkers up till mid-game are easily delt with by Zerglings. Its by no doubt stupid to stick to zerglings and roaches no doubt. Please read that I recommend Broodlords or Swarmhosts. Its just stupid to go roachs heavy if the Protoss have lots of Immortals.......

Comment: That is not how your answer reads. It reads that roach ling is competent and these other things work too. It should read that ling roach will keep you from flopping over dead from a timing but for the love of god get lair tech out asap or swarmhosts thier not quite lair but very good.

Comment: @ClassicThunder Well you should read the question though. Qutoe "How am I supposed to counter this army of his - Stalker / Zealot / Archon / High Templar ? How should I deal with his army as zerg?" It says nothing about Immortals and mass Zealots..... It would be a total different question. So yet again, I strongly disagress with your comments.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of going all in you need to force the protoss to fight on multiple fronts. Build your forces with speed in mind, and attack on multiple sides at once if possible. Preferably some distance apart, IE: Their army mid map, AND their base across the map.  Also you can use banelings and zerglins in multiple hit and run skirmishes forcing them to either use their storms or fall to the banelings. Creep spread is a MUST.

Additionally the Infestor's Neural Parasite would be a big help here if you can manage to snag a few templar with it. Or their fungal growth, as it's essentially the same thing as psionic storm.

Answer (score 1):

> How am I supposed to counter this army of his - Stalker / Zealot /
>   Archon / High Templar ? How should I deal with his army as zerg?

I really think the other answers here are bad so here's my take on the situation.

Zerg vs Toss is very tricky because its very timing based. You dont want to make a single unit until you econ is set up. Don't have enough econ you loose. Don't have enough army you loose. So scouting and memorizing the list of toss timing attacks is very important.

The first sign of a Stalker/Zealot/Archon/High Templar is usually a 2 base timing that can be scouted by very early natural gasses. Early gasses indicate tech which should trigger you to be really greedy. Make a pair of lings and get your 3 bases saturated asap. Not making units seems a weird way to counter an all in but having a massive econ for when you do start making units is super important.

Make sure you send in overseers around 7:00 to see what it is. There is a immortal/collosus allin and stargate allins and blink stalker allins and all sorts of shenanigans the toss might be up to.

These all ins can be broken into two catagories.

> Hi tech

- Immortal/Collosus
- Anything templar tech based <-- The build in question

You cant reliably hold these things with lair tech which is why scouting is so important. You should go for mutas, swarmhosts, or roach hydra.

Against robo tech, mutas are the best counters, swarmhosts are pretty good, and roach hydra is good if you get vipers out and have good control.

Against templar tech mutas are pretty good if you are good at handling base races. Let your 3rd die spine the hell out of your natural and keep running out of storm. Roach hydra works pretty well to but is really micro intensive and requires a lot of focus. Its really hard to macro properly behind proper roach/hydra usage and if you mess up once too hard your army melts.

What you want are swarmhosts behind a wall of spines. Make as many hosts as your gas will allow a ton of spines and a few extra queens to inject the spines and you should be golden.

> Low tech

- Blink Stalker
- Immortal Sentry

Low tech allins can be crushed with lair tech. Roaches, roach ling, ling hydra, and roach hydra work all really well. These compotitions rely on your massive 3 base econ to be overwhelming so keep injecting and make sure you have good creep.

Comment: +1. Thank you for your answer. I actually was looking for something considering the micro management and the right unit composition rather than timing attacks, economy harrassment etc. Can you add those recommendations to your answer if you have any?

Comment: @Volkanİlbeyli I'm not sure what you mean, I suggest a comp and amount to macro to survive the various types of attacks you face from Protoss.